# How to transform JSON into HTML in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am a total newbie to Angular and I am running into an issue that I can't quite find the answer to on the existing documentation.

Essentially I have a controller that fetches json data:

```
...
$http.get("/json/blabla").success(function(result) {
$scope.information = (function () { return result; })();
```

Then in my template
`<div ng-controller="myController">`
`<div>{{information}}</div>`

The data that is returned from json looks like this:
`<p><strong>something</strong> blabla </p><p>something else</p>`

In my final html output the `<p>` and other tags are printed without being converted into HTML... I read that you are to use the `$compile` feature in angular for this but I can't seem to find an example to use it for something as simple as this.

Any advice would be appreciated!
Thanks
- V

Comment: Could you give us a sample of your json that is being returned?

Comment: Sure, the json basically returns an object with a bunch of properties such as `title`, '`image.src` and so on. There is an `information` property that contains inline html as i mentioned above `<p><strong>...etc` - using `$sce.trustAsHtml` did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you utilize the `ngBindHtml` attribute for the `<div>`, it will load as HTML instead of text, you should be able to set it up with...

```
<div ng-bind-html="information"></div>
```

This should produce the desired results, though you will need to first install ngSanitize so that the HTML can be properly rendered in a secure way.

To install ngSanitize, first download the script and include it wherever you are calling your scripts, then, in your module dependency list, add `ngSanitize` resulting in something similar to...

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you that helped. I ended up doing this in my controller (it was only one property in the json that was coming through as HTML - which I already had sanitized in my main CMS): `$scope.information_sanitized = $sce.trustAsHtml(result.info);` (result is the data coming from the JSON feed)...